# Create solid scenekit node that the camera can't go through it

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I want to create a "solid" SCNNode, so when the camera touches the node, it will stop moving. I've tried physics but it didn't work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question does not help with the problem. I am going to assume you have a player object moving through a scene. If you want to disable the camera moving you have to set a condition for when the player collides with that solid object to stop the camera in update.

Comment: Currently, I'm moving only the camera, but I think that I'll add a player node. Tnx (: